# Why the Objective-C cannot use 'self' object in protected function-pointer?

Tags: ios, function-pointers, protected

I want to use 'protected' in Objective-C , so I write the FatherView class and the AView class :

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, DisplayViewT) {
    DisplayViewT_One ,
    DisplayViewT_Two ,
};

@interface FatherView : UIView{
@protected
    UIView *_test_one_view ;
    UIView *(*_testV_funcp_void)(DisplayViewT displayT) ;
}
@end
```

in FatherView class , the _testV_one_view property is a function pointer,
you can see the FatherView's implementation :

```
@interface FatherView()
@property (nonatomic , strong) UIView *test_two_view ;
@end

@implementation FatherView

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init] ;
    if( self ){
        self->_test_one_view = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
        self.test_two_view = [[UIView alloc] init] ;       
        self->_testV_funcp_void = (UIView *(*)(DisplayViewT))[self methodForSelector:@selector(test_func_testV:)] ;
    }
    return self ;
}
- (UIView *)test_func_testV:(DisplayViewT)displayT
{
    UIView *displayV = nil ;
    switch (displayT) {
        case DisplayViewT_One:{
            displayV = self->_test_one_view ;
        }
            break;
        case DisplayViewT_Two:
        default:{
                displayV = self.test_two_view ;
            }
            break;
    }
    return displayV ;
}
@end
```

AView class is the FatherView class' subclass :

```
@interface AView : FatherView
- (void)exc_teest ;
@end
@implementation AView
- (void)exc_test
{
    UIView *oneV = self->_testV_funcp_void(DisplayViewT_One) ;
    NSLog(@"%@",oneV) ;
}
@end
```

Question :
the AView have a method ,the method's name is exc_test ,
I invoke to the method (exc_test) .

But Xcode print result : null !

Why ? AView is FatherView's subclass , _test_one_view is FatherView's property , _test_one_view is created in FahterView's init method , I want to print FahterView's property (the property is _test_one_view) in AView class ,but the result is null , Why ?

I don't know why ...

I want your help , thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the declare type of  `testV_funcp_void`,

we know that `methodForSelector` returns the type `IMP`, the real `IMP` is `typedef id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...)`, but now you set the `IMP` to `UIView *(*_testV_funcp_void)(DisplayViewT displayT)`

the correct type should be `UIView *(*_testV_funcp_void)(UIView *v , SEL sel, DisplayViewT displayT)`, 
this is the right way as follows,

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, DisplayViewT) {
    DisplayViewT_One ,
    DisplayViewT_Two ,
};


@interface FatherView : UIView{
@protected
    UIView *_test_one_view ;
//    UIView *(*_testV_funcp_void)(DisplayViewT displayT) ;
    UIView *(*_testV_funcp_void)(UIView *v , SEL sel, DisplayViewT displayT) ;
}
@end

@interface FatherView()
@property (nonatomic , strong) UIView *test_two_view ;
@end

@implementation FatherView

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init] ;
    if( self ){
        self->_test_one_view = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
        self.test_two_view = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
        self->_testV_funcp_void = (UIView *(*)(UIView *, SEL, DisplayViewT))[self methodForSelector:@selector(test_func_testV:)] ;
    }
    return self ;
}
- (UIView *)test_func_testV:(DisplayViewT)displayT
{
    UIView *displayV = nil ;
    switch (displayT) {
        case DisplayViewT_One:{
            displayV = self->_test_one_view ;
        }
            break;
        case DisplayViewT_Two:
        default:{
            displayV = self.test_two_view ;
        }
            break;
    }
    return displayV ;
}
@end

@interface AView : FatherView{
@protected

}
@end

@implementation AView

- (void)exc_test
{
    UIView *oneV = self->_testV_funcp_void(self, @selector(test_func_testV:),  DisplayViewT_One) ;
    NSLog(@"%@",oneV) ;
}

@end
```

Comment: I have another question . If I want to use function-pointer to point to a Objective-C method ( not to point to IMP ) , how to do ? I don't know how to write . Please Help , thanks .

Comment: `IMP` is an alias of function pointer. The first argument is a pointer to `self` and second argument is `method selector` , you are using  function-pointer to point to a Objective-C method

Comment: So , If use ' protected ' in  Objective-C ，Do we must to use IMP and we must defined a function-pointer with 3 argument  ? in Cpp , We can defined a function-pointer and use 'protected' to decorate this function-pointer . In Cpp , it's so easy

Comment: refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime/imp   From memory, an IMP is a memory-address just like a function pointer, and can be invoked just like an ordinary C function. However it is guaranteed to use objective-C messaging convention as we talked before(the params).

Answer (score 0):

Casting a selector to a function pointer is the problem. Use a block.

The function pointer is not unique per instance - it is a pointer to the implementation of the method for all instances and does not store the "self" pointer along with it.

Comment: thank you . If use block , How to use 'protected' to decorate this block ? I want to protected the block .